# How to compute cumulative and one specific column in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, dplyr, group-by

I have the data about sales by years and by-products, let's say like this:

```
Year <- c(2010,2010,2010,2010,2010,2011,2011,2011,2011,2011,2012,2012,2012,2012,2012)
Model <- c("a","b","c","d","e","a","b","c","d","e","a","b","c","d","e")
Sale <- c("30","45","23","33","24","11","56","19","45","56","33","32","89","33","12")
df <- data.frame(Year, Model, Sale)
```

Firstly I need to calculate the "Share" column which represents the share of each product **within each year**.

After I compute cumulative share like this:

[image]

In the 3rd step need to identify products that accumulate total sales up to 70% in the **last year** (2012 in this case) and keep only these products in the whole dataframe + add a ranking column (based on last year) and summarises all the rest of products as category "other". So the final dataframe should be like this:

[image]

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fairly complex data wrangling task, but can be achieved using `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Sale = as.numeric(Sale)) %>%
  group_by(Year) %>%
  mutate(Share = 100 * Sale/ sum(Sale),
         Year_order = order(order(-Share))) %>%
  arrange(Year, Year_order, by_group = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(Cumm.Share = cumsum(Share)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(below_70 = Model %in% Model[Year == max(Year) & Cumm.Share < 70]) %>%
  mutate(Model = ifelse(below_70, Model, 'Other')) %>%
  group_by(Year, Model) %>%
  summarize(Sale = sum(Sale), Share = sum(Share), .groups = 'keep') %>%
  group_by(Year) %>%
  mutate(pseudoShare = ifelse(Model == 'Other', 0, Share)) %>%
  arrange(Year, -pseudoShare, by_group = TRUE) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(Rank = match(Model, Model[Year == max(Year)])) %>%
  select(-pseudoShare)
#> # A tibble: 9 x 5
#>    Year Model  Sale Share  Rank
#>   <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#> 1  2010 a        30 19.4      2
#> 2  2010 c        23 14.8      1
#> 3  2010 Other   102 65.8      3
#> 4  2011 c        19 10.2      1
#> 5  2011 a        11  5.88     2
#> 6  2011 Other   157 84.0      3
#> 7  2012 c        89 44.7      1
#> 8  2012 a        33 16.6      2
#> 9  2012 Other    77 38.7      3
```

Note that in the output this code has kept groups `a` and `c`, rather than `c` and `d`, as in your expected output. This is because `a` and `d` have the same value in the final year (16.6), and therefore either could be chosen.

<sup>Created on 2022-04-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: is it possible to add a rank column too?

Comment: @user15330237 yes, but it's even more complex. Do you need the rank to be the rank of the Models in the final year?

Comment: exactly, based on final year

Comment: @user15330237 see my update

Comment: I know it seems difficult but is it possible to do ranking based on real models and categorise 'other' as the last in the ranking? For instance to be a=1, a =2, other=3, instead of a=1, other=2, a =3 (according to last year)

Comment: @user15330237 but that's not what you have in your expected output. You want to change your expected output to something different now?

Comment: yes, only this ranking part

Answer (score 0):

```r
Year <- c(2010,2010,2010,2010,2010,2011,2011,2011,2011,2011,2012,2012,2012,2012,2012)
Model <- c("a","b","c","d","e","a","b","c","d","e","a","b","c","d","e")
Sale <- c("30","45","23","33","24","11","56","19","45","56","33","32","89","33","12")
df <- data.frame(Year, Model, Sale, stringsAsFactors=F)


years <- unique(df$Year)

shares <- c()
cumshares <- c()

for (year in years){
  extract <- df[df$Year == year, ]
  sale <- as.numeric(extract$Sale)
  share <- 100*sale/sum(sale)
  shares <- append(shares, share)
  cumshare <- rev(cumsum(rev(share)))
  cumshares <- append(cumshares, cumshare)
  
}

df$Share <- shares
df$Cumm.Share <- cumshares

df
```

gives

```
> df
   Year Model Sale     Share Cumm.Share
1  2010     a   30 19.354839 100.000000
2  2010     b   45 29.032258  80.645161
3  2010     c   23 14.838710  51.612903
4  2010     d   33 21.290323  36.774194
5  2010     e   24 15.483871  15.483871
6  2011     a   11  5.882353 100.000000
7  2011     b   56 29.946524  94.117647
8  2011     c   19 10.160428  64.171123
9  2011     d   45 24.064171  54.010695
10 2011     e   56 29.946524  29.946524
11 2012     a   33 16.582915 100.000000
12 2012     b   32 16.080402  83.417085
13 2012     c   89 44.723618  67.336683
14 2012     d   33 16.582915  22.613065
15 2012     e   12  6.030151   6.030151
```

I don't understand what you mean by step 3, how do you decide which products to keep?

Comment: as you see in Cum.Share column, e + d +c give you 67% of the share so <70%. Now I need to keep only these 3 (e ,d,c) and categorise/summarise a+b as 'other'